# Running Tasks Asynchronously In CMD

Tags: image, batch-file, asynchronous, cmd, parallel-processing

I am working on modifying the script my company uses for imaging pc's. I noticed that in our current script tasks are started like the following example:

```
@echo off
firststep.bat
secondstep.bat
thirdstep.bat
```

When running I notice that tasks happen one after another. My idea is to run asynchronously when possible. I looked up several examples of asynchronous process running for CMD and I found two ways that are supposed to run processes asynchronously. They are as follows:

```
@echo off
REM First Example
start firststep.bat
start secondstep.bat
start thirdstep.bat
```

and:

```
@echo off
REM Second Example
start /b firststep.bat
start /b secondstep.bat
start /b thirdstep.bat
```

I have read that /b signifies you want to run a binary process, but I do not understand fully what the difference between start /b and start is. Which of these is more preferable to be used in this circumstance? Would either of these effectively accomplish my goal of expediting our imaging process or should I be using a different way?

Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: You have `/B` wrong... http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/b runs the program in the same window, without it each process would run in another window which closes when it exits.